# PHP and C# Different Unicode Output

Tags: c#, php, encoding, utf-8, urlencode

Hi I have a multilingual line: "Hindi - हिंदी , Chinese - 痴呢色 ，Russian - руссиан"

I need to perform an URLEncode on it after cnverting it into UTF8 in both PHP and C#.

```
<?php
$sms_text = 'Hindi - हिंदी , Chinese - 痴呢色 ，Russian - руссиан';
$encoded_text = utf8_encode($sms_text);
$message = urlencode($encoded_text);

echo $message;
```

Output: 
**(Correct)**

> Hindi++-+%C3%A0%C2%A4%C2%B9%C3%A0%C2%A4%C2%BF%C3%A0%C2%A4%C2%82%C3%A0%C2%A4%C2%A6%C3%A0%C2%A5%C2%80+%2C+Chinese+-++%C3%A7%C2%97%C2%B4%C3%A5%C2%91%C2%A2%C3%A8%C2%89%C2%B2+%C3%AF%C2%BC%C2%8CRussian+-+%C3%91%C2%80%C3%91%C2%83%C3%91%C2%81%C3%91%C2%81%C3%90%C2%B8%C3%90%C2%B0%C3%90%C2%BD

But when I use c#:

```
string msg = "Hindi - हिंदी , Chinese - 痴呢色 ，Russian - руссиан";
var a = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
msg = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(a);
Console.WriteLine(msg);
```

It gives me following output **(Incorrect)**

> Hindi+-+%e0%a4%b9%e0%a4%bf%e0%a4%82%e0%a4%a6%e0%a5%80+%2c+Chinese+-+%e7%97%b4%e5%91%a2%e8%89%b2+%ef%bc%8cRussian+-+%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd

Can anyone please help me to fix my C# code.

Comment: try `HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode`?

Comment: Please see my dotnet fiddle, the output is quite different than what I have in PHP : https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/xJxjgj

Comment: use `mb_convert_encoding` for converting charsets in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You have error in php code. Just write this:

```
$sms_text = 'Hindi - हिंदी , Chinese - 痴呢色 ，Russian - руссиан';
$message = rawurlencode($sms_text);
```

and this in C# project

```
string msg = "Hindi - हिंदी , Chinese - 痴呢色 ，Russian - руссиан";    
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(msg, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: I tried same on https://dotnetfiddle.net/xJxjgj but the output is not same as PHP

Comment: Is there any workaround, by which I can get the same output as PHP

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a couple of issues here -

The php you have isnt giving you the correct result - `$encoded_text = utf8_encode($sms_text);` that part is causing some mangling and shouldnt be needed.

Beyond that in the C# code you are calling `msg = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(a);` this is causing you to url encode the Type of a, and not the string. Again all you should need to do is

`UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
string utf8Encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(msg,utf8);`

something like that, if you ditch the mangling encode from your PHP and only do a straight utf8 url encode on the string .. they end up coming out the same in both C# and PHP

Comment: `utf8_encode` is only meant for `ISO-8859-1` string and should not be needed anyways